# Slurm: Schedule Job Arrays to Minimal Number of Nodes

Tags: slurm

I am running Slurm 19.05.2 with Cloud nodes only. I specified

```
SelectType              = select/cons_tres
SelectTypeParameters    = CR_CORE_MEMORY,CR_CORE_DEFAULT_DIST_BLOCK
```

To make sure that a node is fully utilised before allocating a second node.

It seem to work well with jobs that have many tasks. If I have 8 nodes which each have 16 cores and I submit a job which has 8 tasks and each task requires 2 cores this will be scheduled to one node.
For example the script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=batch
#SBATCH --output=o_batch.%A.%a.txt
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=8
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 2
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=100

srun hostname
```

will output

```
node-010000
node-010000
node-010000
node-010000
node-010000
node-010000
node-010000
node-010000
```

If I specify a job array with `--array=1-8` (`--ntasks=1`) all jobs of the array will be scheduled on a different node (even though one node could fit all job requirements)

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --job-name=array
#SBATCH --output=array.%A.%a.txt
#
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=10:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=100
#SBATCH --array=1-8

srun hostname
```

will output

```
node-010000
node-010001
node-010002
node-010003
node-010004
node-010005
node-010006
node-010007
```

Is there a way of configuring slurm to behave the same with arrays as with task?